# How to kill a thread spawned from a JavaFX controller when the view closes

Tags: java, javafx

I have this and it works fine:

```
    private Timeline heartbeat;
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        startHeartbeat();
    }
    private void startHeartbeat() {
        heartbeat = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                  System.out.println("beep");
            }
        }));
        heartbeat.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        heartbeat.play();
    }
```

However, when the view closes, the thread persists. Where do I put code to terminate the thread?

Comment: Note you're dealing with an animation, not a separate thread; animations are executed on the _JavaFX Application Thread_. You need to call `Animation#stop` when the view is closed. How you know when the view is closed depends on what exactly the view is. If it's something like a `Window` or a `Tab` then you can observe it for close events.

Comment: @slaw I figured I had the terminology incorrect! :)